# How to set Photoshop CC window size to 1280x720 via AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to resize the Photosshop CC window to 1280x720 to record it in 720p. I tried multiple ways, including AppleScript, SizeUP! app, terminal etc but none work.

Here's an example of AppleScript I'm using:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Adobe Photoshop CC" 
    display dialog (get name of window 1) 
    set position of window 1 to {50, 50}   
    set size of window 1 to {1280, 720} 
end tell
```

It does set the position, but does not set the size of the application window.

When I try

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Adobe Photoshop CC"
           tell window 1
            set {size, position} to {{1280, 720}, {150, 150}}
            end tell end tell
```

I get the error `"System Events got an error: Can’t set application process \"Adobe Photoshop CC\" to {1280, 720}." number -10006 from application process "Adobe Photoshop CC"`

I have also tried to set bounds instead of size with the following code to no avail.

```
set the_application to "/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC/Adobe Photoshop CC.app"
tell application the_application
    activate
    set bounds of window 1 to {1, 1, 1281, 721}
end tell
```

and I get `"Adobe Photoshop CC got an error: Can’t set window 1 to {1, 1, 1281, 721}." number -10006 from window 1`

SizeUP! app does change the position but does not effect the Photoshop window size.

Does anyone know how can I resize the Photoshop application window on a Mac to 1280x720 to record it in 720p?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! [Cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956088/how-to-set-photoshop-cc-window-size-to-1280x720-via-applescript) is not allowed - questions should be posted on a single site only and will be migrated to another site if necessary. You can request a migration on your question by flagging for a moderator with a custom flag reason.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate your problem as I don't own Adobe Photoshop, but it seems extremely likely that the process you're trying to tell s.th. to is *NOT* named *"Adobe Photoshop CC"*.
(Did happen to me once, too ...)

My guess is supported by the fact that I could *exactly* reproduce your error messages by using "Safari" as placeholder but mis-spelling it "SafariX" in the script.
Try this command in Script-Editor (with Photoshop running) to find out:

```
tell application "System Events" to get processes whose ¬
name starts with "ph"
```